# How to add a new column with matching string from another file

Tags: python

I have two files

file1:

```
chrom start     end       strand somecol1...somecol10
11  98566330    98566433    -
11  98566295    98566433    -
11  98566581    98566836    -
```

file2

```
chrom   start   end      strand  gene_id            gene_name
11  98566330    98566433    -   ENSMUSG00000017210  Med24
11  98566295    98566433    -   ENSMUSG00000017210  Med24
11  98566581    98566836    -   ENSMUSG00000017210  Med24
```

desired output

```
chrom start     end       strand gene_id gene_namesomecol1...somecol10
11  98566330    98566433    -   ENSMUSG00000017210 Med24
11  98566295    98566433    -   ENSMUSG00000017210 Med24
11  98566581    98566836    -   ENSMUSG00000017210 Med24
```

How can I insert new columns with matching string values in my file1 with out changing the structure or elements in other columns (from somecol1...somecol10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If putting the output in a different file is not a problem you could do this:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2, open('file3.txt', 'w') as f3:
        lines2 = f2.readlines()
        for idx, line1 in enumerate(f1.readlines()):
                # for each line in f1, we get the same line from f2
                line2 = lines2[idx]
                # compare that the first 4 columns are equal
                if line1.split()[:4] == line2.split()[:4]:
                        # if so, combine the data and save it to file3. The format in which I wrote the data to file3 is irrelevant.
                        f3.write(line2.strip() + '\t' + '\t'.join(line1.split()[4:]) + '\n')
```

Comment: I need it in the same file

Comment: You can't append content to a file line. After doing that, you can rename the file to replace the original one.

Comment: `line2 = lines2[idx]`  not sure where line2 is called.

Comment: In the if statement

Comment: sorry can you please walk me through the code with comments?